# Splunk: Is there a way to get warning lights in Splunk dashboards?

Tags: splunk

I found this really interesting German page (link: https://www.splunk.com/de_de/blog/tips-and-tricks/gesund-und-wach-bleiben-wie-ihr-mit-splunk-daten-in-bessere-raumluft-verwandelt.html) with a dashboard where some warning lights are included:

[image: dashboards]

The warning lights are based on which values are predicted for different queries. I am now wondering how one could get this warning lights (and also the predictions based on the MLTK for certain variables) within a dashboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in Splunkbase, I think you want to install:

## [image][Traffic Light Visualizations](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1923/)

[image]

Comment: Yes, this looks like that what I want. Thanks! I will do some research before accepting your answer :-D